# How should I express fractions like 15/16ths in HTML?

Tags: html

I know there are HTML entities for 1/2, 1/4, and 3/4, but are there others? Like 1/3 or 1/8? Is there a good way to encode arbitrary fractions?

Comment: Horizontal line request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript

Answer (score 43, accepted):

how about <sup>15</sup>⁄<sub>16</sub>? (<sup>15</sup>&frasl;<sub>16</sub>)

Comment: Ideally would use `&frasl;` for the slash

Answer (score 29):

```
1/2 → &#189; or &frac12;
1/4 → &#188; or &frac14;
3/4 → &#190; or &frac34;
1/8 → &#8539; or &frac18;
3/8 → &#8540; or &frac38;
5/8 → &#8541; or &frac58;
7/8 → &#8542; or &frac78;
1/3 → &#8531;
2/3 → &#8532;
1/5 → &#8533;
2/5 → &#8534;
3/5 → &#8535;
4/5 → &#8536;
1/6 → &#8537;
5/6 → &#8538;
```

...but you could also encode them as decimals: 15/16 = 0.9375 ;)

Comment: The equivalent decimal codes do, however, appear to work for ⅛ to ⅞ in IE. I'll update my answer to include them.

Answer (score 11):

For the existing fractions as Unicode codepoints (which are mapped to by HTML entities), search for "vulgar fraction" in the [Unicode Character Names Index](http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex3.html).

Now, for generic fractions, which work in HTML but also work in plain text, use the super- and subscript digits (see [Unicode Codepoint Chart](http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/), search for "Superscripts") separated by the [fraction slash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm) character.

Your example implemented as above:

## ¹⁵⁄₁₆

Answer (score 1):

Isn't just 15/16ths alright? Or even 15/16<sup>ths</sup> (`15/16<sup>ths</sup>`)?

Comment: There's no need to spell out the "ths".  15/16 is pronounced "fifteen sixteenths".

Answer (score 1):

For more complex scenarios there is also [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/). The support for this is slowly getting better. Internet Explorer seems to lag behind with this as well.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, this can be done with Unicode code 2044, preceded by &#x and ending with a semicolon. The whole thing is placed between the numerator and the denominator.

For instance, with this solution, 15 divided by 16 in HTML is rendered like this: 15⁄16

This works for combinations of integers acting as numerators and denominators.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your exact needs and audience.
For most purposes many methods would be appropriate.
15/16, 15 parts of 16, 93.75%,  <sup>15</sup>/<sub>16</sub>  all mean the same,
you might even use symbols like 
++++++++++++++-

For some more complex scenarios you will need more complex solutions more like LaTeX than html. I believe there are also server side components that take LaTeX descriptions and create images that are browser compatible, such as described here: http://www.fauskes.net/nb/htmleqII/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a standard called [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/). But is for XML unfortunately. However if you have more expressions you might consider switching to basic XML.