# Is there a simple way to place a line between two lines of text?

Tags: html

For instance, instead of having `a+b/c`,  I want the '`a+b`' part on top of the '`c`' part with a line in between.

I have tried using a fraction line like so `<sup>a+b</sup>&frasl;<sub>c</sub>` but instead it just produces this <sup>a+b</sup>⁄<sub>c</sub> as opposed to a horizontal line with the text directly above and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) will allow you to include Latex or MathML formulas in your HTML.  MathJax can also be configured to use native MathML rendering when available in a browser, and only fall back to HTML-CSS mode when native rendering is not available.

Answer (score 2):

There's [LaTex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), which is used by math.stackexchange.com. You can also use something like [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML).

Answer (score 2):

check this

CSS

```
.fraction, .top, .bottom {
    padding: 0 5px;    
}

.fraction {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;    
}

.bottom{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="fraction">1/2</span>
<span class="fraction">3/4</span>
<span class="fraction">1/32</span>
<span class="fraction">77/102</span>
```

JQuery

```
$('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
    var split = $(this).html().split("/")
    if( split.length == 2 ){
        $this.html('
            <span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span>
            <span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>
        ')
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xW7d8/

source : [How to display "Classic" built-up fractions with an horizontal line in CSS / JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KG Traditional Fractions 2](http://www.fontspace.com/kimberly-geswein/kg-traditional-fractions) font! It is free for personal use!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="top">2</div><div class="bottom">6</div>​
```

CSS

```
.top{border-bottom:solid black 1px; display:inline-block; float:left}

.bottom{ display:inline-block; clear:left; float:left}
```

Source: [How to display "Classic" built-up fractions with an horizontal line in CSS / JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript)