# Fixed width for a div put content inside will scale it self

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a fractional calculator, and I have two questions.

1) The result part of my calculator is fixed , so it result that if the text is longer than the width will be covered. How do I make the font size scale itself according to how long the answer is so it will show all the number.

2) What is the best technique to make the fraction. I'm currently using three divs. One for the whole number, one for numerator and for denominator. Is there a better way to do this?

TQ

Comment: Try mathquill in javascript using fractions

Comment: can you show your code here?

Comment: 1) It's really more complex than you're likely looking for 2) [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13878815/2065702)