# How can I go about making this work with dynamically generated content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried using the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript) to display fractions. The problem is I don't know how to make it so that it will work on dynamically generated fractions. Here is the jQuery code block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main').on('click', '#startButton', function () {
        $('#startButton').hide();
        $('#main').html('<div class="progress">progress</div><hr><div class="questions"><span class="fraction">1/2</span></div><hr><div class="answers">answers</div>');
    });

    $('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
        $this = $(this);
        var split = $this.html().split("/");
        if(split.length == 2){
            $this.html('<span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span><span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>');
        }    
    });

});
```

I realize that the .each() function does not work because it is passing an object into `#main`. **Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q29Qx/) illustrating my problem.** Click "placeholder for start button" to see the fraction

Comment: Store the function in `each` and call it on your newly inserted nodes whenever you append new nodes.

Comment: whats the issue with just placing the $('.fraction') inside the on('click') function?

Comment: you can check for changes to the dom like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div and then run the fraction code on anything you find

Comment: @clancer It never occurred to me to have the function nested inside the .on() function. Thank you, and for that extra link too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the each function inside onclick to invoke.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main').on('click', '#startButton', function () {
        $('#startButton').hide();
        $('#main').html('<div class="progress">progress</div><hr><div class="questions"><span class="fraction">1/2</span></div><hr><div class="answers">answers</div>');

        $('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
        $this = $(this);
        var split = $this.html().split("/");
        if(split.length == 2){
            $this.html('<span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span><span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>');
        }    
    });

    });



});
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sentmca/kj6Us/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main').on('click', '#startButton', function () {
        $('#startButton').hide();
        $('#main').html('<div class="progress">progress</div><hr><div class="questions"><span class="fraction">1/2</span></div><hr><div class="answers">answers</div>');

    $('.fraction').each(function(key, value) {
        $this = $(this);
        var split = $this.html().split("/");
        if(split.length == 2){
            $this.html('<span class="top">'+split[0]+'</span><span class="bottom">'+split[1]+'</span>');
        }    
    });
    });


});
```