# Problems displaying fractions

Tags: html, fractions, displayobject

i want to make buttons which insert a fraction into a texterea. Some fractions are displayed well, but some are displayed as their HTML code:

½ ==> ½
but
&frac24; ==> &frac24;

Can anyone explain me why randomly some fractions are displayed well and some not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's explained at [Writing Fractions in HTML](http://changelog.ca/log/2008/07/01/writing_fractions_in_html) with a reasonable workaround.

Comment: I,ve fount that page, but the problem is not how to write fractions, but displaying them. Some fractions are displayed well but others like &frac24; is displayed as '&frac24;' instead of 2/4

Comment: The `&frac` part is not an instruction to the browser to draw the following two digits as a fraction.

Comment: 'SO' answer: [3878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript). May be useful: [Writing-Fractions-On-Web-Pages-Correctly-With-Entities](http://demosthenes.info/blog/566/Writing-Fractions-On-Web-Pages-Correctly-With-Entities). Internet search: 'display fractions in HTML'.

Answer (score 0):

`&frac24;` does not translate correctly because it is not a valid HTML entity (or fraction actually; 2/4 == 1/2).

Here's a list of the valid fraction entities in HTML:

- ¼ = `&frac14;`
- ½ = `&frac12;`
- ¾ = `&frac34;`

Comment: Thanks, that explains why &frac26; didnt worked, but why doesnt &frac17; work and &frac18; does work?

Comment: Because they're not actually part of the entity schema.