# how to show text like 2 / 4 "page number / total pages" in css or css3

Tags: html, css

I wish to show my text like "Current page number / Total pages" using CSS

[image]

Html code :

```
<p class="pagenumber> 2 / 5 </p>
```

Can you assist?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878772/how-to-display-classic-fractions-in-css-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan No, not a duplicate of that, this is more about how to style the **layout of the text** I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with two extra elements for the numbers and a pseudo element for the dividing line.

You still need to adjust it for your design and layout to make it look good.

```css
.pagenumber {
  position: relative;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
.pagenumber:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.pagenumber .current {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 0.5em;
}
.pagenumber .total {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagenumber">
  <div class="current">2</div>
  <div class="total">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.pages {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: table;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-style: italic;
}
.pages * {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.pages sup {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  text-align: right;
}
.pages sub {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 15%;
  text-align: left;
}
.pages span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 350%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="pages">
  <sup>6</sup><span>/</span><sub>7</sub>
</p>
```

Comment: what about linear wipe for text, is this possible in css ?

Comment: You would be better off by making a totally new question for that.

Comment: ya but i need to wait 90 more min to post new one. :)